# Remove specific character in a line from a text file

Tags: python, file, txt

My text file is:

```
CREATE TABLE `redirect` (
`rd_from` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`rd_namespace` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`rd_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`rd_interwiki` varbinary(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`rd_fragment` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),
KEY `rd_ns_title` (`rd_namespace`,`rd_title`,`rd_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

My goal is to remove the text, which is:

```
,
PRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),
```

I am using this code (PYTHON) (does not accomplish my goal). Your help is highly valued.:

```
with open('filepath.txt', 
                mode = "r", errors='ignore') as file:

    with open("filepath.txt", mode = "w", errors='ignore') as newfile:
             
            badline = [",\nPRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),"]
            for lines in file:     
                for word in badline:
                 lines = lines.replace(word, ' ')
                newfile.write(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

with `file.readlines()` you'll need to loop over the lines, and your search for `badline` will not match anything, since the lines break at each `\n`.

Instead you could use `file.read()` to get a single string:

```
badline = "\nPRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),"

with open('filepath.txt', mode = "r", errors='ignore') as file:
  remaining = file.read().replace(badline, '')

with open("filepath.txt", mode = "w", errors='ignore') as newfile:
  newfile.write(remaining)
```

Furthermore, if you remove *both* the preceding *and* the following `,` you may be breaking your file-content's syntax:

```
badline = [",'\nPRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),"]
```

becomes

```
badline = "\nPRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),"
```

...or read up on the command-line tool `sed` ‍♂️

Comment: The read() reads every single character separately. Thus, unlikely to read the variable badline.

Comment: What makes you say that? The `.replace(badline, '')` seems to process the total file contents, and replace the [updated] target string as expected...?